# Java drawing rectangle upside down with varying heigth

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to create a bar chart with `g.fillRect(x, y, width, height)`. However, when I set the height negative so it should draw upwards, it doesn't draw the rectangle.

```
g.fillRect(x, y, 100, -h);
```

The value of int h is described in a sinus function and I want it to move accordingly however I get this weird output that it only draws the top- and the bottom-most pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
g.fillRect(x, y - h, 100, h);
```

instead.